# to include square bracket into single json element in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm creating a function to export a JSON to a specified format. I need to include a square bracket within a single element. As you can see "details_order" contain a single element with curly brackets, all I need is to add an additional square bracket into it. Please advise, thanks

original output:

```
[
    {
        "reference": "20190531",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": "12345",
                "label": "22776",
                "address": "ABC, Apple road",
                "details_orders": {
                    "ref": "AB07-332C"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

expected output:

```
[
    {
        "reference": "20190531",
        "orders": [
            {
                "id": "12345",
                "label": "22776",
                "address": "ABC, Apple road",
                "details_orders": [
                    {
                        "ref": "AB07-332C"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encode your data structure into JSON format, just make sure the "ref" value is stored in an array inside the "details_orders" array.

Here's an example of how the data should be structured in PHP to output the desired JSON:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reference] => 20190531
            [orders] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12345
                            [label] => 22776
                            [address] => ABC, Apple road
                            [details_orders] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ref] => AB07-332C
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Here is how you could initialise such an array in PHP:

```
$data = [
    [
        "reference" => "20190531",
        "orders" => [
            [
                "id" => "12345",
                "label" => "22776",
                "address" => "ABC, Apple road",
                "details_orders" => [
                    [
                        "ref" => "AB07-332C"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Hi Julian, appreciate your answer but I have difficullty to manipulate existing code because it using

$output->addChild() function to add the data

I'm new to JSON, would like to know any other functions to format the above original output becomes expected output? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Julian, currently i have a question related to this post, wonder if you can solve it? please check at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514045/force-to-add-array-into-single-element-of-json-in-php-integrated-to-plugin)
thanks